# Spring boot + Activiti explorer

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, alfresco, activiti, spring-boot-maven-plugin

Is it possible to integrate activiti explorer maven plugin with activiti Spring boot app?, so that we can make use of activit-explorer to view deployed process in activit-spring boot engine.

I know we can use rest-api over spring boot to query process engine, but I want to know if it is possible to run the explorer over spring boot by adding it as a maven plugin during deployment?Or can we tweak the activit-explorer.war somehow to point to spring-boot activiti engine?

Comment: can you please elaborate on your requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of answering my own question so that it will be useful for other developers with similar requirement. If you want to make an eco-system where activiti-rest, explorer and your custom end points co-exist, please refer this thread from activit forum. I have tried this and is working fine. [link to thread](https://forums.activiti.org/comment/31135#comment-31135)

Answer (score 1):

activiti-explorer.war is standalone webapp by itself. I've write some guideline on how to manually to embed activiti-explorer to you own app. http://blog.canang.com.my/2016/05/12/embedding-activiti-explorer-to-your-application/

Most probably step 5 in my blog is your solution.

btw, there's reason why the name is 'default'. I can't recall it atm

Comment: Can you put a summary of the answer here so that if your blog site goes down future visitors will still be able to learn from this answer?

Comment: Indeed, the link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give my observation here. In order to avoid getting into pulling source and trying to build myself, I achieved partial success, by installing the activit-explorer as part of the usual standalone installation.Started the standalone activiti-explorer using Apache-Tomcat but I configured the database for Activiti as same as (MYSQL in my case) I used in my spring-boot application to hit the common ground.

But apparently the activiti version in my spring boot app was 5.19.0.0 and that for activiti-explorer was 5.22.0.0, which created some misalignment for spring boot application startup to fail. I am hopeful that with matching versions it might succeed. When I get some more time on me I will try and update. Since then may be someone can use this route.